# ExtJS Integration of CKEditor

Tags: extjs, ckeditor

We plan to use ExtJS with CKEditor.

I saw that there is a port of TinyMCE for ExtJS.

Is it be possible to write a CKEditor wrapper for ExtJS?

What I am concerned most about is the event handling (ExtJS defines its own implementation).

I found some information about the TinyMCE port for ExtJS: https://github.com/Qtx/TinyMCETextArea5/blob/master/doc/instructions.pdf

Thank you for sharing your experience about this topic in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extension for ExtJS 3 available on GitHub:

https://github.com/tocco/extjs3-ckeditor-extension

We use it in production, it works fine.

Comment: Thank you I will check if it works in the latest ExtJS version.